# JqueryCode to convert current page to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I need some pointer or client side (Jquery code) to convert current web page to PDF....PDF page contain content and few images.

Requirement is to include all content from webpage in PDF 
but optionally if possible to include image as well then nothing like that.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046187/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-html-web-page

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript

Comment: you can see here:
[Download a div in a HTML page as pdf using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem? If so enter your own answer or select one of the answers provided as the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this github repo https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
But it has no support for CSS as I know

Answer (score 0):

Try the JsPDF library that will do this for you very easily. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/bu9db10d/embedded/result/)

If you click on the top right corner you can see the code for the result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var doc = new jsPDF();


var specialElementHandlers = {
'#editor': function(element, renderer){
    return true;
}
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 15, 15, {
'width': 170, 
'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
   });
});
```